# jquery breaks other scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of, I know nothing about scripting, and barely HTML.

Anyway, i found this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showThis2(x) {
      $("#NContent").html(  $("#"+x).html());
    };
    </script>

<a href="#Nut" onclick="showThis1('1');">1</a>
<a href="#Nut" onclick="showThis2('2');">2</a>

<div id="NContent"></div>
```

This works perfectly as it should, but it breaks other scripts on my site.

I've googled I should use:

```
var jQuery_latest = $.noConflict(true);
```

But I can't make it work, i'm probably not placing it correctly or something.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: go through all script tags in source view and provide list of what's there ( from src of each tag). If jQuery already loaded in page, won't need to create a `noConflict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
var jQuery_latest = $.noConflict(true);
```

Then `$` variable is not jQuery anymore. You have to change your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showThis2(x) {
      jQuery_latest("#NContent").html(jQuery_latest("#"+x).html());
    };
</script>
```

Be careful not to add load several times jQuery, it could create conflicts too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've loaded jQuery twice.  Try removing the first script tag and see what happens.

Also, jQuery 1.3.2 is *really* obsolete.  1.10.2 is the latest.